# print specific column with specific output field separator

Tags: awk

```
cat A.tsv
1,a,d
2,b,e
3,c,f
```

```bsh
$ awk -F ',' -v OFS="," '{print $2, $3}' A.tsv 
a,d
b,e
c,f
```

- I expected the following 4 commands to give the same results as above:

```bsh
$ awk 'FS=","; OFS=","; {print $2, $3}' A.tsv 
1,a,d
1,a,d
,
2,b,e
2,b,e
b,e
3,c,f
3,c,f
c,f
```

```bsh
$ awk -F ',' 'OFS=","; {print $2, $3}' A.tsv 
1,a,d
a,d
2,b,e
b,e
3,c,f
c,f
```

```bsh
$ awk -v OFS="," 'FS=","; {print $2, $3}' A.tsv 
1,a,d
,
2,b,e
b,e
3,c,f
c,f
```

```bsh
$ awk -F ',' 'FS=OFS; {print $2, $3}' A.tsv 
1,a,d
a d
2,b,e
 
3,c,f
```

Can someone explain why the last 4 commands have different results than the first?

Refer: [Difference between awk -FS and awk -f in shell scripting - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830238/difference-between-awk-fs-and-awk-f-in-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Awk programs consist of `pattern {action}` pairs, where `{action}` is performed if `pattern` evaluates TRUE. If `pattern` is omitted, it is assumed TRUE by default, while if `{action}` is omitted, the default action is `{print}`.

In

```
awk 'FS=","; OFS=","; {print $2, $3}' A.tsv
```

you have:

1. pattern `FS=","` which assigns `,` as the value of `FS`, and as a side effect evaluates TRUE, triggering the default action `{print}`
2. pattern `OFS=","` likewise assigns `,` to `OFS`, evaluates TRUE and triggers the default `{print}` action a second time
3. action `{print $2,$3}` with no pattern, so the default TRUE is assumed and the action is triggered. However `FS` was not set to `,` until the first record had already been processed, so `$2` and `$3` are both empty (since awk used the default whitespace `FS` to parse the first record, assigning the whole record to `$1`). On subsequent records, it prints the expected comma-delimited values.

You probably intended to assign `FS=","` and `OFS=","` in an action before record processing begins - that's the function of a `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=","} {print $2, $3}' A.tsv
```

or

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $2, $3}' A.tsv
```

Alternatively, you can pass variable assignments as arguments before the filename argument(s) (this is sometimes useful if you are processing multiple files and want to set different field separators for each)

```
awk '{print $2, $3}' FS="," OFS="," A.tsv
```

Comment: Is it equivalent to `awk -F ',' -v OFS="," '{print $2, $3}' A.tsv `

Comment: Or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ... '`.

Comment: I know all the AWK documentation says "pattern" but it's all wrong. Awk is made up of `<condition> { <action> }` statements, not `<pattern> { <action> }` statements. The latter made some sense in the very first awk version which really only did pattern matching but is woefully misleading and outdated for any awk version since the 1980s. In what way is `foo == 17` a pattern? It's not, it's a condition. In what way is `TRUE` a pattern? It's not, it's a condition. When we write `if (X) <action>` in C, we don't say X is a pattern, it's a condition. And so on...

Comment: @Porcupine no, `awk '{print $2, $3}' FS="," OFS="," A.tsv` is similar to `awk -F ',' -v OFS="," '{print $2, $3}' A.tsv` but it's not equivalent. They are different in when the assignments take effect (in BEGIN for `-v`, after it for arg list), and whether or not escape sequences get translated (they do for `-v`, they don't for arg list) and whether or not they are stored in ARGV and impact ARGC (they do not for `-v`, they do for arg list).

Comment: @EdMorton I used to be in the habit of referring to them as `rule {action}` but I seem to remember I was "corrected" on that ...

Comment: Some people refer to the whole `<condition> { <action> }` statement as a "rule" (we just saw such a reference on the bug-gawk mailing list IIRC), but for me "rule", like "pattern", is kinda vague and needs to be defined in any given context. You can't go wrong with saying `<condition> { <action> }` - that is 100% accurate and unambiguous.